# Angular front end: strange Chrome behavior with 2 devices

Tags: google-chrome, angular

I have a local Web Site created in Angular 2. I access to my Web Site via: http://192.168.1.17/.

I have this strange situation:

- On my phone, I go on my Web site (http://192.168.1.17/).
- Then, on my computer, I do the same: I go on my Web site.
  Finally, I scroll the web page with my mouse and I see the page scrolling automatically on my phone !

Why there is a communication between my two devices ? Is it a communication coming from Chrome ?

Note: if I 'Inspect' the page in Chrome, I don't see transfer on network in 'Network' tab.

Comment: That's the browsersync feature of your HTTP server.